# Basic of Event and Delegate. Event Subscribe line of PropertyChange Event from INotifyPropertyChanged in the class using it

Tags: c#, wpf, events, delegates, inotifypropertychanged

Hi I learned about event and delegate from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQgwEsJISy0&t=1230s. In this he says To make the event we need three step

1. Define a Delegate
2. Define an event based on that delegate
3. Raise that event

I followed him and made the app in Console but since i am working in WPF I will post the code that i used in WPF here and the code is as below:

```js
namespace WpfApp5
{
    public delegate void step1DelegateDefinition(); // Step-1: Define a delegate

    public interface INotifyOnVideoEncoded
    {
        event step1DelegateDefinition EventDefinedInInterface;// Step-2a:  Define an event based on that delegate
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyOnVideoEncoded
    {
        public event step1DelegateDefinition EventDefinedInInterface; //Step-2b:  Define an event based on that delegate

        public MainWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           this.DataContext = this;
           ObservableCollection<string> NotificationText = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            EventDefinedInInterface += SubscriberMethodForConection;// A method corresponding to delegate is subscribed for that event 
            Encode();
        }

        public void Encode()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Encoding Video...");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            PublisherMethodForConnection(); //Step-3: Raise an event
        }

        public void PublisherMethodForConnection()
        {
            if (EventDefinedInInterface != null)
                EventDefinedInInterface();
            else
                MessageBox.Show("No Subscriber");
        }

        public void SubscriberMethodForConection()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MailService: Sending an email...");
        }
    }       
}
```

So from this whats my knowledge is

> An Event has to be Subscribed in order to execute using += sign.

But in contrast to my knowledge when I use propertychange event from INotifyPropertyChange there is no need of += sign. and moreover the strange is it seems the +=(subscribing to event) is done dynamically but because if i first initialize property (in my case presented in code below if i initialize the value of FirstName=Jeff and LastName=Buckley) then it fires the else part in my code and shows the message "There is no Subscriber to which MyOnPropertyChanged function can call " in the beginning. I believe it is because the event subscriber is null(i.e. there is no += event assigning statement like i expect) but later once the window is loaded it seems like there is the event subscriber although i didn't do it on the code. Below is my code Implementing propertychanged.

```js
namespace UnderstandingINotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _FirstName;
        private string _FullName;
        private string _LastName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _FirstName; }
            set
            {
                if (_FirstName != value)
                {
                    _FirstName = value;
                    MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod("FirstName");
                    MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod("FullName");
                }
            }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _LastName; }
            set
            {
                if (_LastName != value)
                {
                    _LastName = value;
                    MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod("Lastname");
                    MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod("FullName");
                }
            }
        }
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return _FullName = _FirstName + " " + _LastName; }

        }

        private void MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("There is no Subscriber to which MyOnPropertyChanged function can call ");
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FirstName = "Jeff";
            LastName = "Buckley";
            this.DataContext = this;
           
        }
    }
}
```

So my confusion is in the first code i have to assign the event using +=, but in the second code it works without doing += . I cannot figure out that how the second code ran without using += as event need to be linked using += to the subscriber.

I tried to read online and see videos for explanation but couldn't understand which is the reason i am asking here. So far i have learned many things from here thank you for that and thank you for taking your time to read this question too, I can grasp this with all your help.

Comment: You are implementing the interface, which means you typically only fire the event by your `MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod` (which is a strange name). It is the consumer of the event that subscribes to it. For example a Binding.

Comment: The method that fires the event is typically called NotifyPropertyChanged or RaisePropertyChanged, and should have a single line: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`

Comment: @Clemens thank you for your reply , what i am confused of is, if MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod is the function that is tied to the event PropertyChanged then don't we have to do something like PropertyChanged+= MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod in order to invoke it  or since I am calling it in setter of my property so we I don't have to do += in this case. I am confused as we are using += in the another example to link a method to an event and not here( EventDefinedInInterface += SubscriberMethodForConection) and not in this one.

Comment: No, we don't. As already said, you do not subscribe to the event on the producer side. You only fire it by `PropertyChanged?.Invoke`.

Comment: @Clemens I have changed my code according to your suggestion about name and using the ? operator instead of If else. Meanwhile i also wanted to ask is it possible to change my code(2nd code) to use += rather  than calling the event tied function in setter of property provided i want the same function. If you have any source it would be great and again thank you for your reply :D

Comment: So it means, if i had the event in another class than my main window then i had to use += for subscribing. I will try to change the location of the method NotifyPropertyChanged (old MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod ).  i will post down the changed code as an answer, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer.**

First code sample subscribes `EventDefinedInInterface` inside `MainWindow.ctor()` and raises it inside `PublisherMethodForConnection`.

Second code sample does not subscribe `PropertyChanged` at all. It just raises this event inside `MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod`.

**Long answer.**

Usually, events are intended to notify *external* subscriber(s) about some changes occurred inside object (property has been changed its value, video has been encoded, etc.).

While *technically* you can subscribe your own event, usually this doesn't make a sense. E.g., if `MainWindow` instance wants to do something, when `LastName` was changed, it can handle this inside property setter or `MyOnPropertyChanged_PublisherMethod` method. There's no need for event subscription.

So, when you want to *subscribe* an event of some object, you *must* use `+=` syntax to add your event handler. When you want to raise an event, you usually call private or protected method, which does this, but *this is not* event handling/subscription.

Below are three links to read before implementing event in C#:

- [Event Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/event)
- [Standard .NET event patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern)
- [How to: Publish Events that Conform to .NET Framework Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines)

Answer (score 0):

I hope with the descriptions provided above and playing with the code below, others can also take the benefit

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

```js
namespace UnderstandingINotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        Class1 Class1Object = new Class1();
        private string _FirstName;
        private string _FullName;
        private string _LastName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _FirstName; }
            set
            {
                if (_FirstName != value)
                {
                    _FirstName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
                }
            }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _LastName; }
            set
            {
                if (_LastName != value)
                {
                    _LastName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Lastname");
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
                }
            }
        }
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return _FullName = _FirstName + " " + _LastName; }

        }

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));           
        }
        Class1 ObjectOfClass1 = new Class1();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FirstName = "Jeff";
            LastName = "Buckley";
            this.DataContext = this;
            PropertyChanged += ObjectOfClass1.MethodToBeTracked;
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public void MethodToBeTracked(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("propertychanged event fired due to change in property " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

> XAML of for running in WPF

```html
<Window x:Class="UnderstandingINotifyPropertyChanged.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UnderstandingINotifyPropertyChanged"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="400">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,30,0,0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <Label Content="First Name : "  />
            <!--<TextBox Width="200" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName,Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>-->
            <TextBox Width="200" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                <Label Content="Last Name : "  />
                <!--<TextBox Width="200" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>-->
                <TextBox Width="200" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <Label Content="Full Name : "  />
            <!--<TextBox Width="200" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=FullName,Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>-->
            <Label Width="200" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=FullName,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```